# how do i write shell script to run multiple instances of a flask app on several ports?

Tags: python, flask

Shell script to run multiple instances on 5000,5001,5002 ports.
the code is written in python and run on flask
Trying to run this command for now:

```
  $flask run -h localhost -p 5000
  $flask run -h localhost -p 5001
  $flask run -h localhost -p 5002
```